# Javascript, dynamic css and transform

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, transform

I have a problem with javascript. I need to change a div's class dynamically using .classeName = "..." but it doesn't update itself. For example, I have put a transform into my class. It does a scale and set the transform-origin but nothing appears on my screen. Here's my code:

```
var panier = document.getElementById("panier");

if (panier.style.display == "none" || panier.style.display == "")
{
    panier.className = "";
    panier.style.display = "block";
    panier.style.webkitTransform = "scale(0, 0)";
}

if (panier.className.search("enleverPanier") >= 0)
    panier.className += panier.className.replace("enleverPanier", "afficherPanier");
else
    panier.className += " afficherPanier";
```

As you can see, my class afficherPanier does a scale(1,1). The div keeps it's scale(0,0) that I set in case the div isn't visible.

Here's my css

```
.afficherPanier {
 -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
 -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
   -o-transform-origin: left top;
      transform-origin: left top;

 -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
 -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);}
```

Do you know why the scale(1,1) doesn't work?
Thank you! :)

Comment: `transform` is not supported in all browsers. Use a browser's web inspector to see if the class is being applied as expected, rather than relying on a visual result.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by a suggested edit. They were all there before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I'm pretty sure className is being changed to enleverPanierafficherPanier. To fix this, try changing

```
panier.className += panier.className.replace("enleverPanier", "afficherPanier");
```

to

```
panier.className = panier.className.replace("enleverPanier", "afficherPanier");
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't see that, but I still have the same problem: scale(1,1) doesn't do anything.

Comment: In that case, would you mind sharing your code (CSS, Javascript, AND HTML) on jsfiddle and posting it here? It would be extremely helpful.

Comment: When I put it on jsfiddle, the page is totally broken. :(

Comment: Anyway, here's the source code (with no meta/include) http://jsfiddle.net/thecheeselover/p2Kqa/

Comment: And by the way, to hide the second page (with the size(0,0)) you need to call HidePanier()